How to set both List-Unsubscribe-Post and List-Unsubscribe headers for Microsoft Graph API?
I am trying to set both List-Unsubscribe and List-Unsubscribe-Post headers in a Microsoft graph API call. My code is:
SendMailPostRequestBody sendMailPostRequestBody = new com.microsoft.graph.users.item.sendmail.SendMailPostRequestBody();

        com.microsoft.graph.models.Message message = new Message();
        message.setSubject(emailDetails.getSubject());
        ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
        body.setContentType(BodyType.Html);
        body.setContent(emailDetails.getHtmlBody());
        message.setBody(body);


        LinkedList<Recipient> toRecipients = new LinkedList<>();
        Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
        EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
        emailAddress.setAddress(emailDetails.getTo());
        recipient.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
        toRecipients.add(recipient);
        message.setToRecipients(toRecipients);

Does anyone know how to do this? I saw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1509500/how-to-provide-list-unsubscribe-header-using-micro but I do not understand where id: 'String 0x1045' is mapped to 'List-Unsubscribe'.
Any help would be very much appreciated!
